# What's a term for a motivational phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a term for a motivational or inspirational phrase that one repeats to oneself?  For example, in the movie Cars, Lightning McQueen psychs himself up by saying to himself: "I am speed...I eat losers for breakfast."

Comment: A mantra? A maxim? A slogan?

Comment: Thanks, @Cerberus.  I think "mantra" is pretty close and may be the best.

Comment: BTW, this came up after my three-year-old daughter innocently requested "losers" for breakfast.  It's become our name for Cheerios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is an *affirmation*, or a *self-affirmation*. This term would include other ways to affirm something other than repeatedly vocalising it, but that is a common form.

Colloquially, it might be called a *mantra*. In its original use, *mantras* would be objects of contemplation rather than affirmation, and repeated for a much longer time, but the colloquial use will immediately bring vocal repetition to mind.